# How to add WebServices Server to SpringMVC?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I have a Spring MVC WebApp and it is working perfectly, now i want it to have a soap WebService server.

I tried adding a new class of type Web Service (runtime apache axis2).
this is the content:

```
public class Emails {

    public String Hello (String name){

        return "Hello Email: " + name;

    }

}
```

It successfully generates the wsdl! i can access it and all but when i try to get a response out of it, it gives me the following error:
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

I am suposing this is a problem on my configurations maybe. When i create a project from scratch and its a dynamic web project instead of a spring mvc it works fine.

Any advice?

Comment: `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported` Looks like GET method. Are you sure it's POST?

Comment: I tried with Get also it didnt work

Comment: Please show more relevant code. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has it's own project for doing SOAP Services. The project has name [Spring Web Services](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/). I recommend to use this project as it make SOAP development much more pleasant and integrated well with any existing Spring app.

Comment: Thats what i did. In my existing SpringMvc App i added a WebService type class. It almost works but when making a request gives me the error above...

Comment: You mentuioned Apache Axis. That is different library for doing Web Services.

Comment: ohh i see. anyways i quit using soap and started using rest